# How can I access to the Word Office library once my project is published in the IIS Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

This is the error that the server throw when I want try to access to the Word Library `Microsoft.Interop.Word`

> No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID  Acceso denegado.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} debido al siguiente error: 80070005 Acceso denegado. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
>
> ASP.NET no está autorizado para obtener acceso al recurso solicitado. Considere la posibilidad de conceder derechos de acceso al recurso para la identidad de solicitud de ASP.NET. ASP.NET tiene una identidad de proceso base (normalmente {MACHINE}\ASPNET en IIS 5 o Network Service en IIS 6 e IIS 7, y la identidad del grupo de aplicaciones configurada en IIS 7.5) que se utiliza si la aplicación no se va a suplantar. Si la aplicación se va a suplantar mediante , la identidad será el usuario anónimo (generalmente IUSR_MACHINENAME) o el usuario solicitado autenticado.

Comment: From the error message (I don't speak spanish) it looks like the user under which your IIS server runs doesn't have access to the interop...

Comment: Yes, that´s my problem I can´t access to the library when I publish my project, i tried to give permissions to the folders and libraries but none of this works :(

Comment: Check if running the website as another user works http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Word office **IS** installed on the server????

Comment: Yes, Word office is installed.